# ListView setOnItemClickListener not working when there is a textview multiline

Tags: android, listview, textview, multiline

The following code let the user click on a row and trigger setOnItemClickListener method only on imageview and TextView with ID `android:id="@+id/titulo"`, in the other hand the textView with ID `android:id="@+id/descripcion"` ignores user clicks then the the method setOnItemClickListener is not triggered.

If you look closely the only difference between `android:id="@+id/titulo"` and `android:id="@+id/descripcion"` is the last one has the attribute `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

I have tried almost every combination without success, I have not relevant programmatically code.

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:id="@+id/pnlFila">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:src="@drawable/futbol"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Futbol"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descripcion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Una descripción corta"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="@string/listaTienda"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textColor="#6B8E23"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/lb_categoria"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista_tiendas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="251dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.04"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNuevaTienda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Nueva Tienda"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`? remove it.

Comment: I removed, nothing change :(. I update question.

Comment: remove all `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Comment: @Rustam when I do that all row ignore clicks. At least i need blocksDescendants on outter layout.

Comment: Is there any`ScrollView` in your layout.?

Comment: remove `android:weightSum="1"`

Comment: @Rustam No. All code is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

and:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Try this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/pnlFila">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:clickable="false"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titulo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="Futbol"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descripcion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                tools:text="Una descripción corta jhkjhjkh jhjkhjkh kjhkjhjkhj jhjkhkjh kjhjkhjkh jkhjkhjk"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need multiline. I can't remove it.

Comment: You were right, I don't need `android:inputType="textMultiLine`

Comment: Use in `android:id="@+id/titulo"` tags `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:singleLine="true"`